# What happens when a positively charged ion such as $\rm{O}_2^+$ hits an electrically neutral or positive surface?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, material-science, vacuum, ions

The ionized molecule is ionized by electron bombardment. Considering this problem in a rough vacuum (let's say 0.3 Pa as to somewhat limit background noise if it affects the question), at average speed (room temperature), when the positively charged ion hits a neutral or positive surface what happens? Will it create a spark and destroy the surface? Does it also depend on the reactivity of the surface?

Comment: 1. $O_2$ is neutral. 2. Why do you think any of this will happen? How will a surface, neutral or charged, "spark and destroy" when another charged particle comes in contact? By what mechanism?

Comment: I've edited my question to include that it is positively charged by Electron Bombardment. So it is an o2 ion molecule. By the particles trajectory, if it enters in contact with a positively charged surface, will it depose itself violently and spark(think ion pump or EDM machining), or will it forever repel? And then again, for neutral surfaces, when the charged particle enters in contact at about 500 m/s (actually more because it has been accelerated by electron bombardment) will it collide and spark, therefore destroying a tiny part of the surface?

Comment: If it is a +'vely charged molecular ion, the +'vely charged surface will cause it to scatter (repel). If the surface is neutral, it may just get absorbed into the material or knock some atoms off it, or even cause ionization of atoms on the surface. At high enough energies, other more complicated scattering can happen. Since we are dealing with only one incoming ion, there won't be any visible sparking and certainly no visible destruction. Also, 500 m/s is not that fast for atoms/molecules.

Comment: Could a sufficiently fast particle overcome the force of the charged surface and still colide?